# T-Sql - Select query in another select query takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a procedure with arguments but its calling takes a very long time. I decided to check what is wrong with my query and came to the conclusion that the problem is Column In (`SELECT [...]`).

Both queries return 1500 rows.

First query: time 45 second

Second query: time 0 second

```
1.
declare @FILTER_OPTION int
declare @ID_DISTRIBUTOR type_int_value
declare @ID_DATA_TYPE type_bigint_value
declare @ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE type_int_value 

set @FILTER_OPTION = 8
insert into @ID_DISTRIBUTOR values (19)
insert into @ID_DATA_TYPE values (30025)
insert into @ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE values (10)


SELECT * FROM dbo.[DATA] WHERE
[ID_DISTRIBUTOR] IN (select [VALUE] from @ID_DISTRIBUTOR) 
AND [ID_DATA_TYPE] IN (select [VALUE] from @ID_DATA_TYPE) 
AND [ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE] IN (select [VALUE] from @ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE) 

2.
select * FROM dbo.[DATA] WHERE
[ID_DISTRIBUTOR] IN (19)
AND [ID_DATA_TYPE] IN (30025)
AND [ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE] IN (10)
```

Why this is happening?
How should I create a stored procedure that takes an array of arguments to use it quickly?

Edit:

Maybe it's a problem with indexes? indexes are created on these three columns.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for both queries to examine the differences? If not, this would be the best place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a large performance difference, I would guess that you have one or more indexes.  In particular, if you have an index on `(ID_DISTRIBUTOR, ID_DATA_TYPE, ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE)`, then the second query can make use of the index.  SQL Server can recognize that the `IN` is really `=` and the query is a simple lookup.

In the first case, SQL Server doesn't "know" that the subqueries really have only one row in them.  That requires a different set of optimizations.  In particular, the above index cannot be used, because the `IN` generally optimizes differently from `=`.

As for what to do.  First, look at the execution plans so you can see the different between the two versions.  Then, test the second version with more than one value in the `IN` lists.

If you can live with just one value for each comparison, then use `=` rather than `IN`.

Comment: Yes I have index on `(ID_DISTRIBUTOR, ID_DATA_TYPE, ID_AGGREGATION_TYPE)`